# how to setup icepick on eclipse? What annotation processors to add to factory path?

Tags: android, eclipse, annotation-processing

Using the [icepick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick) library with Eclipse requires configuration of the annotation processor. What libraries need to be added to the factory path so that there are no compilation errors and icepick processes your classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick/issues/17

> You'll need to add icepick, icepick-processor, and guava to your Factory Path.

This looks like this in my Eclipse Preferences for a project using IcePick
[image]